# ffmpeg: Output to the same folder as source with recursive input?

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg

I have a lot of gifs I want converted to webms in many sub directories, and I have this script which will do it, but it will output to the directory where the script is located:

```
for /r %%a in ("*.gif") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -c:v libvpx -crf 12 -b:v 4000k "%%~na.webm"
pause
```

I've tried a bunch of things, but I can't figure out how to get the output to land in the same sub directory as the input file so I can maintain the folder structure.

Edit: it's a Windows batch file I'm using.

Comment: What shell scripting language are you using? Might want to tag the question with that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing two command modifiers for your output filename.

```
"%%~dpna.webm"
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew it'd be something simple.

Comment: @t3hPeNgU1NoFd00m please mark my answer as the answer to your question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers