# run texconv windows batch file, recursively and output to the same folder as source?

Tags: windows, batch-file, recursion

im running texconv-r.bat in this directory:

[image]

I've included "/r" so that it runs recursively on folder "sub" too

```
for /r %%f in (*.jpg, *.png, *.bmp) do ( texconv -pow2 -f BC1_UNORM %%f )
```

however, the output places the contents of the sub directory, in the batch file directory:

[image]

rather, I would like it outputted to the same directory - the sub directory

I cant figure out what i need to change in the batch file to make this work? ive tried what's [recommended in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33266300/ffmpeg-output-to-the-same-folder-as-source-with-recursive-input) but i cant get it to work

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try to double quote %%f ? `...do ( texconv -pow2 -f BC1_UNORM "%%f")`

Comment: Hi SachaDee, unfortunately that does t change anything. Any more ideas?